# Debugging in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have created the breakpoint and started the project in debug mode. But still the execution does not stop at the breakpoints.

I also have some junit classes in the same project, breakpoints are working fine in the junit class.

So can anybody suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working with multiple threads/processes? If so, I recommend using System.err.println's near your breakpoints to see if those breakpoints are ever even being reached.

Comment: The print statements are appearing in the console. So we can be sure that the piece of code is executing.

Comment: How do you run your project? Is it a standalone Java application? Some EAR deployed to JavaEE container? Do you run it from within Eclipse?

Comment: Its a web application and I am running it within the Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 6 update 14? See [279137: Breakpoints fail to hit under JDK 1.6.0_14](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=279137).

Comment: I am using java 5. The breakpoints are working fine for the same version in other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Is that code running in a server? If your code is running in an application server or servlet container the server needs to be started in debug mode to break.

Comment: I have started the server in debug mode.. still the breakpoints are not working :-(